# Integrating a php/js function to calculate time remaining with a PDO generated table

Tags: javascript, php

Both the first & second code blocks work perfectly in isolation, though I'm at a loss as far as integrating the two.

I would like to use the response & createdon results from the db fetch to display time remaining within the table on the response row. (how long until the specified response time is elapsed. I'm at a loss as to how to integrate the two code blocks to achieve this result.

Sorry that i aren't articulating myself very well. Without further knowledge it's difficult to know how to stucture my question efficiently.

```
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
?>
<table class="ticket-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Brief Description</th>
        <th>Open Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Severity</th>
        <th>Response</th>
        <th>Recovery</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>Select</th>
        <?php $test  = 10; ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php foreach($result as $data) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $data->id; ?> </td>
            <td><?= $data->type; ?> </td>
            <td><?= $data->brief; ?> </td>
            <td><?= $data->createdon; ?> </td>
            <td><?= $data->status; ?> </td>
            <td><?= $data->severity; ?> </td>
            <td><?= $data->response; ?> </td>
            <td><?= $data->recovery; ?> </td>
            <td><?= $test; ?> </td>
            <td>
                <a href="../pages/admin-select-ticket.php?id=<?= $data->id; ?>" class="selectbutton">Select</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>


    <!--Count Down Timer (needs response (timelimit) & createdon as inputs)-->
    <!--===========================================================================================-->

    <?php
    $timelimit = '10 mins';
    $createdon = new DateTime("2022-04-15 23:15:33");
    $createdon->modify('+'.$timelimit.'');
    $date= $createdon->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    ?>

    <div id="data">

    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>">

    <script>
        function func() {
            var dateValue= document.getElementById("date").value;

            var date =  Math.abs((new Date().getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0));
            var date2 = Math.abs((new Date(dateValue).getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0));
            var diff = date2 - date;



            var days = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
            var hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600) % 24;
            var mins = Math.floor(diff / 60) % 60;
            var secs = diff % 60;

            if (hours < 10) {
                hours = "0" + hours;    // add leading zeros
            }
            if (mins < 10) {
                mins = "0" + mins;    // add leading zeros
            }
            if (secs < 10) {
                secs = "0" + secs;    // add leading zeros
            }

            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = days + " days, " + hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
        }
        func();
        setInterval(func, 1000)
    </script>
```

Comment: I have answered your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71875708/subtracting-an-interval-from-string-various-units-of-time-using-strtotime) yesterday.

Comment: I don't see how this question is even related to PHP, let alone PDO